# ERC20 totalSupply Best practice

Tags: solidity, erc20

Best Practice Advice:

Is it acceptable to override the totalSupply() of an ERCToken if you're using a different variable to hold some of the supply and not holding all the tokens in the totalSupply variable directly?

example:
...

```html
uint _extraSupplyForGivingAway = 1e27; //decimal 1e18 * 1M just an example

function totalSupply() public view override returns(uint totalSupply){ 
    totalSupply = super.totalSupply() + _extraSupplyForGivingAway);
    return (totalSupply);
}
```

The total value of the contract is not only the _totalSupply, it's also the _totalSupply and the extra tokens.

Question: Does the community and/or exchanges find this acceptable or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different issues here.  One is, are you conforming to the EIP-20 (ERC-20) standard in a way that will be understood by the community-at-large?  Another is, is this a reasonable implementation for your business logic?

The latter issue is out-of-scope here since you haven't really provided enough information.  So I will address the first, which is what I believe you wanted to know.

The reason I spell this out is because you fixate on implementation details but ERC20 is an interface standard, so it doesn't by-and-large dictate how things ought to be implemented.

In the case of `totalSupply`, all [the standard says](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) is:

> totalSupply
> Returns the total token supply.
>
> `function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)`

If it's not clear what that means, the EIP does link to the [OpenZeppelin contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/9b3710465583284b8c4c5d2245749246bb2e0094/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) as an example implementation, which has:

```
/**
* @dev Total number of tokens in existence
*/
function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
  return _totalSupply;
}
```

So as long as the total number of minted tokens is returned, you are fine.  It doesn't matter if you internally have it computed as the sum of two other private variables.  I do have some lingering doubts about your implementation from what you wrote, but as I said, that's out-of-scope :)

I hesitate to add this and possibly muddy the waters but.. "tokens in existence" is somewhat ambiguous.  Sometimes people have their burn function do an actual transfer to the zero address (not just the event), effectively removing them from the circulating supply, and adjust the total supply accordingly.  So their `totalSupply` will then return the number of tokens held only by non-zero addresses.  Block explorers may or may not account for this.  I would avoid doing this unless you absolutely know what you're doing.